# Query to sum some of the values

Tags: mysql

Ive got a simple query that is used on a search. My problem is with this query is that as the records in mysql are added everytime there is a transaction, the query returns a list of data when there could only be one or a few more rows instead of a lot more.

[SQLFliddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cab6b5/17)

As you can see here - the query returns a lot of rows, where I want it to return

```
BLSH103  A001A  31  24/01/2014
```

Can the qty where the product name & pallet space are the same be summed? And then show the largest date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use a sum function on t.Quantity (and a group by clause)

```
SELECT  (t.ProductName) as Pname ,(s.PalletSpace) as PSpace, sum(t.Quantity) as Qty,(t.TransactionDate) as Transac
  FROM PalletSpaces s
  JOIN ProductTrans t
   ON s.PalletSpaceID = t.PalletSpace
 WHERE t.ProductName LIKE 'BLSH103' OR s.PalletSpace LIKE 'BLSH103'
group by 
 Pname, 
 pSpace, 
 Transac -- if you want to group by date also...
```

By the way, using LIKE this way (without `%`) doesn't make much sense...

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cab6b5/20)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use GROUP BY and SUM in this way:

```
SELECT  (t.ProductName) as Pname ,(s.PalletSpace) as PSpace, SUM(t.Quantity) as Qty,(t.TransactionDate) as Transac
  FROM PalletSpaces s
  JOIN ProductTrans t
   ON s.PalletSpaceID = t.PalletSpace
 WHERE t.ProductName LIKE 'BLSH103' OR s.PalletSpace LIKE 'BLSH103'
GROUP BY t.ProductName, s.PalletSpace;
```